# Some sprite Images not appearing

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5, cpu-usage

My app was rejected and a screenshot was taken with the some sprites not appearing. I found that quite surprising since everything seemed to be okay in Xcode but after following the instructions to archive and install the app through iTunes I was able to reproduce the issue. I am not quite sure what caused some of the sprites not to appear, but I realized that when testing that just before the game starts there is a brief spike of up to 70% CPU usage (which is owed to several spritesheets that I am using). Could this spike in CPU usage prevent some sprites from appearing? How could I possibly load the sprites gradually to avoid such a high spike? What could be the other issues causing the some sprites not to appear?

Comment: if it is working fine then , i suggest you to make one distribution ad-hoc profile profile and using that try to run your application in your device. You might get what is the problem.

Comment: I am not sure whether what you've suggested is diferent from what I've done. After I archived the app I distributed it using the Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Deployment option, then I saved the .ipa file and opened it on my phone through iTunes. Is what you're recommending any different?

Comment: yes, what you have done is another way.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the app from your device. In Xcode run "Clean" from the project menu. Build & run again. A common issue is to remove resources from your app but not seeing the effect until the app bundle is removed from the device because Xcode will never remove files from an already deployed bundle. Check that the missing sprites are indeed added to the project.

Next build your app in Release configuration to ensure it runs the same code path as the archive build.

And then test on all Simulator variants. Does the app run on each standard, Retina, widescreen or iPad device on iOS x, y, z? Where xyz are all versions supported by your app.

CPU spikes will never cause resources not to be loaded. That would be a pretty unreliable system.

Comment: I did as you recommended but the sprite is still not appearing

Comment: I just checked my spritesheet size, it is 217x2027 which I believe falls below the limit for spritesheet size on the iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are not naming your resources correctly?

The simulator is not case sensitive but the devices are so it is very possible to have a sprite sheet named SpriteSheet.png load fine on the simulator by calling it spritesheet.png in code, but when you run this on a device it will not load.